# Qt c++ application autostart on android tv

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-tv

I have a QT application written on C++. It is working fine on all android/Linux/windows devices. But I want to make it run on android enabled TV. I also want to make it run and when the TV is turned on.
Google shows me that the application must use leanback libraries. But is it possible to use these libraries inside C++ Qt application ?
Is it possible at all to run this APK when the TV is turned on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the architecture is correct (ARM/x86), you need to mark it as AndroidTV. This link may be useful to you. https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html#tv-activity